# PHP 5.3.29 on Ubuntu 16.04 in order to run Joomla 1.5 locally

Tags: joomla1.5, php-5.3, ubuntu-16.04

I'm working on a Joomla 1.5 website, which was developed with PHP 5.3. Now I'm having some incompatibilities issues with some components.
My machine runs Ubuntu 16.04.
The version of Joomla is 1.5.
PHP versions are 5.6 and 7.0 (apache is configured to run PHP 5.6)

I can't find a way to download and install it. The apt command only shows 5.5, 5.6, 7.0 and 7.1 PHP versions.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You can check this lnk http://askubuntu.com/questions/462673/installing-php-5-3-in-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: This is not an issue of joomla its your configuration issue of localhost server at ubunu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have joomla 1.5 on a website running. My config shows that PHP 5.4.16 is in use. Therefore, why dont you try it with PHP 5.4 and get it from the download page:

http://php.net/releases/

If you have troubles to install it on your computer. Take a look here:
https://serverfault.com/questions/353550/how-to-install-old-php-version

The link explains how you install a old php version on linux. Btw.: in the link it is only explained how to replace a PHP version. But it is possible to run different versions on a server.

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.